# Can I implement a function or better a decorator that makes func(a1)(a2)(a3)...(an) == func(a1, a2, a3,...,an)?

Tags: python, function, decorator

for example, function 'add' can be used like this:

input:

```
add(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

output:

```
10
```

or input:

```
add(1)(2)(3)(4)
```

output:

```
10
```

or input:

```
add(1, 2)(3, 4)
```

output:

```
10
```

Comment: Does that really work? `func(a1)(a2)(a3)` looks like three function calls: `func(a1)` returns a function, that is called with `(a2)` which is *also* a function, which gets called with `(a3)`. OK, I can see that happen with a wrapper, but just looks wrong:D

Comment: It's possible (there is an answer around here somewhere that does it). The trick is something like having `add` be a callable instance of a subclass of `int`.

Comment: Good; that is a better duplicate than the one I was going to use :)